# How do I fill a cell in the table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I fill a cell in the table dynamically after the user selects an option within the column?

Inside the select there is an update function and it is working, but I can't update column two of the line with the data given value of the select.

```js
function update(line) {
    // update in the col of mytable for next col.
    // whats wrong with this code? 
    // Why not working?
    var td = line.closest('td');
    td.nextSibling.innerText = line.value;       
}
```

```html
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Selection</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                        <select id="item1" onChange='update(this)' class='options' name='choice'>
                            <option value='option1'>option1</option>
                            <option value='option2'>option2</option>
                            <option value='option3'>option3</option>
                            <option value='option4'>option4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id='emilio'>
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                        <select id="item1" onChange='update(this)' class='options' name='choice'>
                            <option value='option1'>option1</option>
                            <option value='option2'>option2</option>
                            <option value='option3'>option3</option>
                            <option value='option4'>option4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: function is `update` and not `onChange(update)`...

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thank you so much!!!

**update(line) {
 var td = line.closest('td');
 td.nextSibling.text = line.value;
}**

Don`t working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `onChange` is working, you need to select the containing `td` then update then next one like:

```
function onChange(update) {
            var td = update.closest('td');
            td.nextElementSibling.innerText = update.value;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 

**update(line) { var td = line.closest('td'); td.nextSibling.text = line.value; }** 

Don`t working

Comment: You're welcome! I have updated the answer it's `td.nextSibling.innerText` not `td.nextSibling.text`

Comment: Thank you so much but I try to understand and I can't. 

I read this **"td.nextSibling.innerText"  and "td.nextSibling.text"** and I don't understand how it's make work for me!

Comment: @EmilioDamiSilva sorry I have found the issue and updated the answer. Change `nextSibling` to `nextElementSibling` to select the next column.

Comment: Working for me now. Thank you so much! Thank all!

Comment: Can you make one more item: how to move for the next "td"  if I have others? By the way: working perfectly for me now! I am so grateful!

Comment: I am not quiet sure what you mean but you can do something like `td.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerText = update.value;` if you have to skip a td.

Answer (score 1):

Your function name should be update, try this

```js
function update(e) {
            //update in the col of mytable for 0
            if( e.id ==='item1'){
             document.getElementById('selection1').innerHTML= e.value
            }else{
             document.getElementById('selection2').innerHTML= e.value
            }
           
        }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Selection</td>
                <td>Value</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                        <select id="item1" onChange='update(this)' class='options' name='choice'>
                            <option value='1'>option1</option>
                            <option value='2'>option2</option>
                            <option value='3'>option3</option>
                            <option value='4'>option4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td  id='selection1'>
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class='form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12'>
                        <select id="item2" onChange='update(this)' class='options' name='choice'>
                            <option value='option1'>option1</option>
                            <option value='option2'>option2</option>
                            <option value='option3'>option3</option>
                            <option value='option4'>option4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id='selection2' ></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I And I understood until now, but I want the value to be in the column td value within the select line itself, can you help me?

Comment: I made changes to the code snippet in my answer above, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I can't name all the columns in the table as you did, the table is dynamically assembled and this makes it have hundreds of rows, **how can I directly access the selected row?** 

But your answer worked and I will mark it as the best answer, thanks for your help and your time! I appreciate it!